# PHP receiving black instead of js variable sent?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am making a simple web app, in one part of it, I have to send a js variable to PHP. I am sending the JS variable using AJAX but PHP is receiveing blank instead of the data.

Here is the JS function:

```
function sync(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","sync.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var data = "data=thisisdata";
console.log(data);
xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
return $_POST["data"];
?>
```

The output that I get at the console is:

```
data=thisisdata                                                  goal.js:23
                                                                 goal.js:16
```

i.e., I am getting a blank instead of the responseText. I am NOT getting any errors.

What's wrong? What should I do?

Comment: Try `echo $_POST["data"];` instead of `return $_POST["data"];`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: you are not printing the data out. try `dd($_POST["data"]);` or `var_dump($_POST["data"]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
<?php
return $_POST["data"];
?>
```

to

```
<?php
echo $_POST["data"];
?>
```

or to see all posted variables

```
<?php
  echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to echo the response on the PHP side :

```
<?php
echo $_POST["data"];
?>
```